# Getting Wrong Date Using XMLGregorianCalender

Tags: java, xml, calendar, xmlgregoriancalendar

I am trying to get the current date/time to populate in an XML. I am using the code

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlDate = null;
try {
    xmlDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH+1, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Calendar.HOUR, Calendar.MINUTE, Calendar.SECOND, DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED, TimeZone.LONG).normalize();
    lastUpdatetDateTime.setTextContent(xmlDate.toXMLFormat());
} catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
}
```

But I get the output as 0001-03-05T10:11:13Z, from all I know, we are in 2017! :)

Even the time is 8 minutes slower. I ran this at 11:21 AM CST.

Comment: [`Calendar.YEAR`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#YEAR) is a contanst that represents the year field, not the year value (and its value is 1, that's why you're getting year 0001). You should use the year value instead (such as `2017` or whatever value you want). The same for the other fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the arguments you're passing in to [`newXMLGregorianCalendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html#newXMLGregorianCalendar-int-int-int-int-int-int-int-int-):

```
[...].newXMLGregorianCalendar(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH+1, 
   Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Calendar.HOUR, Calendar.MINUTE, Calendar.SECOND,
   DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED, TimeZone.LONG).
```

The `Calendar.YEAR`, `Calendar.MONTH` etc values are *constants*, used to refer to specific parts of a calendar. You'd typically use them like this:

```
Calendar calendar = ...;
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
// etc
```

If you want to create an `XMLGregorianCalendar` for the current date/time, it looks like you need to do that explicitly:

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
xmlDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregoriantCalendar(
    calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
    calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1,
    // etc
    );
```

Better, use the `java.time` classes instead if you possibly can - the `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` classes are really nasty compared with either `java.time` or its backport.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `newXMLGregorianCalendar()` you are expected to provide the year, month, day, etc of the date you want to create.

Your code passed instead the internal constants that designate the various fields, which are going to be small integers totally unrelated to today's date or anything else.

You need to modify that line to provide the actual values for the date/time you want to create.  For example:

```
GregorianCalendar now - new GregorianCalendar();
xmlDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(now);
```

Comment: Thanks guys for solutio guys! That helped!